# using alias name in sql server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

let me first i put my code :

```
SELECT   REPLACE(SUBSTRING(CreateDate,3,8),'/','') as registerdate, 
FROM     TatEstelam.dbo.tblInquiryRealForeigners RL 
         LEFT JOIN TatEstelam.dbo.CustomerInfo  CINFO
             ON RL.IdentificationDocumentNumber = CINFO.NationalID
WHERE-- NationalID <> '0001'
         IdentificationDocumentNumber <> ''
         AND registerdate BETWEEN '910404' AND '950505'
```

my problem is that i cant use alias as column . i mean , in last line , i want call the alias but i cant .
for example i want use this code for time function :

```
AND registerdate BETWEEN '910404' AND '950505'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said you can't use alias in where clause - it's true.
You should use whole expression instead as below.

```
SELECT   REPLACE(SUBSTRING(CreateDate,3,8),'/','') as registerdate, 
FROM TatEstelam.dbo.tblInquiryRealForeigners RL 
LEFT JOIN TatEstelam.dbo.CustomerInfo  CINFO
      ON RL.IdentificationDocumentNumber = CINFO.NationalID
WHERE-- NationalID <> '0001'
IdentificationDocumentNumber <> ''
AND REPLACE(SUBSTRING(CreateDate,3,8),'/','')  BETWEEN '910404' AND '950505'
```

Comment: oh thnx  , ididnot know that .

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
  SELECT   REPLACE(SUBSTRING(CreateDate,3,8),'/','') as registerdate, 
  FROM TatEstelam.dbo.tblInquiryRealForeigners RL LEFT JOIN TatEstelam.dbo.CustomerInfo  CINFO
  ON RL.IdentificationDocumentNumber = CINFO.NationalID
) AS registerdate 
WHERE-- NationalID <> '0001'
   IdentificationDocumentNumber <> ''
   AND registerdate BETWEEN '910404' AND '950505'
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a reasonable representation for the date, so you can just change the constants:

```
SELECT   REPLACE(SUBSTRING(CreateDate, 3, 8), '/', '') as registerdate, 
FROM     TatEstelam.dbo.tblInquiryRealForeigners RL LEFT JOIN
         TatEstelam.dbo.CustomerInfo  CINFO
          ON RL.IdentificationDocumentNumber = CINFO.NationalID
WHERE    NationalID <> '0001' AND
         IdentificationDocumentNumber <> '' AND
         registerdate BETWEEN '1991/04/04' AND '1995/05/05';
```

This does assume that the format for `CreateDate` is consistent.  This also has the advantage that it can take advantage of an index on `registerdate`.

As a note:  don't store dates as strings.  SQL Server has very nice support for all sorts of different date types.  Store them as dates, and you won't have to deal with conversion issues.

Comment: this is basic structure of big company  i can not change date time   structure

Comment: @salar . . . In that case, the strings should at least be consistent, so just altering the constants is probably the best solution.